# BOS is hostile - Can I still do their quests?

Tags: fallout-4

I angered the Brotherhood of Steel by taking out a neutral squad (wanted to clap the legendary guy). Now wherever I go, they seem to remember it and try kill me. Can I resolve that without loading an old save?

I didn't do anything for them now, not even the "Fire Support" quest.

Comment: I think that there is a reset for this aggressive behavior.  Try waiting 2 to 7 days in game before meeting with them again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As user fja3omega hinted at, and per [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3swiyp/i_have_angered_the_brotherhood_of_steel/):

> If you go far away from [the disgruntled], then wait in a chair (or whatever) for
>   like 3 or 4 in game days they will get over it and not be hostile (this works with everyone).

Subsequent comments in the linked thread suggest it works.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but this is what helped me back then. I forgot that I didn't answer here myself.

Answer (score -1):

I personally think you screwed your opportunity to do the quests. Did you save before or have you already gone a bit to far from your save. Anyway the Brotherhood squads aren’t very hard to kill. Plus now you can join the institute without any problems. I joined it and became hostile toward the brotherhood. What about if you go on the Prydwen? I remember someone saying that if you kill a unamed soldier in the borherhood, the important people won’t become hostile.

Comment: This seems like sensible advice, but do you have a source for this information? If this is all something you have tried personally, that would be helpful to know.

Comment: I downvoted because this answer was not accurate, at least for my situation and therefore my question. Thank you for trying to help though! Welcome to this community. Downvotes are nothing personal, but it helps other people that find this thread filter the accurate and more correct answers over the other ones. :)